# vba remove comma without removing strikethough

Tags: excel, vba

How am I able to remove the comma without removing the strikethrough format

Example: C418, C419,  <s>C420</s> , C421, C422, C423,  <s>C424</s> 
Expected Result: C418 C419  <s>C420</s>  C421 C422 C423  <s>C424</s>  
Final Result: C418, C419 C420 C421 C422 C423 C424

I am checking to see if that cell contain a strikethrough. By using the Function I am able to detect it. But once I try to remove the comma by using the replace function and replace comma with a blank. The format for the strikethrough will be remove causing the function not to work which will result in a different outcome.

I will like to use the space delimiter to match with the other cell so that I can split the cell value afterwards

```
If HasStrikethrough(BOMCk.Sheets("Filtered RO BOM").Range("B" & LCB)) = True Then
BOMCk.Sheets("Filtered RO BOM").Range("B" & LCB).Value = Replace(BOMCk.Sheets("Filtered RO BOM").Range("B" & LCB).Value, ",", "")
BOMCk.Sheets("Filtered RO BOM").Range("G" & LCB).Value = "strike-off"

ElseIf HasStrikethrough(BOMCk.Sheets("Filtered RO BOM").Range("B" & LCB)) = False Then
BOMCk.Sheets("Filtered RO BOM").Range("B" & LCB).Value = Replace(BOMCk.Sheets("Filtered RO BOM").Range("B" & LCB).Value, ",", "")

End If

Function HasStrikethrough(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    With rng(1)
        For i = 1 To .Characters.Count
            If .Characters(i, 1).Font.StrikeThrough Then
                HasStrikethrough = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: You should use and accept T.M. 's answer.

Comment: Yours is a valid answer, too and both approaches have their merits; mine might be fractionally ahead in this special case :-) @TinMan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative via xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet Value**

The ►`.Value(11)` approach solves the question by a very simple **string replacement** *(though the xml string handling can reveal to be very complicated in many other cases)*:

```
Sub RemoveCommata(rng As Range, Optional colOffset As Long = 1)

'a) Get range data as xml spreadsheet value
    Dim xmls As String: xmls = rng.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet) ' //alternatively: xmls = rng.Value(11)
'b) find start position of body
    Dim pos As Long: pos = InStr(xmls, "<Worksheet ")
'c) define xml spreadsheet parts and remove commata in body
    Dim head As String: head = Left(xmls, pos - 1)
    Dim body As String: body = Replace(Mid(xmls, pos), ",", "")
'd) write cleaned range back
    rng.Offset(0, colOffset).Value(11) = head & body
End Sub
```

**Help reference links**

- [Excel XlRangeValueDataType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.xlrangevaluedatatype)
- [Excel Range Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)

Answer (score 4):

Range.Characters only works if the cells value is 255 characters or less.

`Range.Characters(i, 1).Delete` will delete the commas.  Make sure to iterate from the last position to the first position when deleting.

```
Sub RemoveCommas(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Characters.Count > 255 Then
        MsgBox "Range.Characters only works with String with 255 or less Characters", vbCritical, "String too long"
        Exit Sub
    End If
   Dim n As Long
   For n = Target.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Target.Characters(n, 1).Text = "," Then Target.Characters(n, 1).Delete
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, interesting. Do you have a reference to the 255 char limit?  I did a test with longer text, `Target.Characters(n, 1).Text` works but `Target.Characters(n, 1).Delete` does nothing

Comment: @FunThomas I haven't been able to find any official documentation.  It appears that Excel uses 1 byte to index the characters.  Similarly, `Range.CopyFromRecordset` used to be limited to 32,767 which is the max size of an Integer.

Comment: FYI posted an alternative via XlRangeValueDataType enumeration with the additional advantage that there seems to be no limitation included. :+) @TinMan